# In the face of sexual trauma, do sufferers tend to avoid relationships with the other sex?

Tags: trauma, sexual-assault

People who suffer trauma tend to avoid talking about their traumatic events: I am wondering if this happens in sexual trauma.

My concern is that the brain should not evolve features leading to the  avoidance of sex, because practicing sex is a primary evolutionary advantage (e.g. it is the second level in Maslow's Pyramid).

- Does the brain fail to adopt the most efficient genes replication tendency or
- is the brain's reaction in such a context an exception to the typical trauma response in other contexts?

Comment: Beware that many behaviors (e.g. suicide!) do not give an evolutionary advantage, yet do exist: the fact that a behavior does not yield any evolutionary advantage is not enough to rule out its possibility!

Comment: I am not a specialist, but I think that 1) Maslow's pyramid of need is not so well established (there are alternative theories) and that 2) you do not really need it to argue that the sex drive is "important, evolutionary speaking" ;o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SHORT ANSWER:**
The fact that victims of sexual trauma would tend to avoid sex because it is associated to their trauma would *not* be contradicting evolutionary theory.
Natural selection is strong, but it is not omnipotent!

**LONGER ARGUMENT:**

- Many trauma reactions are counter productive, evolutionary speaking: Take any victim of any trauma, who might be showing any kind of post traumatic disorder: the behaviors induced can be self-harming and anti-social, and are often counter productive in term of survival and reproduction, and are counter selected by natural selection.
- Saying that "X should not exist, because it is counter productive, evolutionary speaking" is akin (apologizing for the caricature here) to say that your arm should not break when you fall from a cliff, because it is not helping you to survive and/or to reproduce, so natural evolution should have selected for stronger arms in humans.
- Any feature has advantages and drawbacks, and evolution is about balancing those two sets: Having stronger bones might require more nutrients to build them and to move a heavier body. A better resilience to sexual trauma might mean less emotional sensitivity.
- And if some contexts (e.g. falling from a cliff, being abused sexually) occurs with a low enough probability, natural selection will *not* select for paying the price to better react to those contexts.